# how to go to next line int WPF C# automatically when the previous line filled?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, line, new-operator

how can I tell it to go to the next line without using "AcceptsReturn=True". I mean I want it to automatically go to the next line just when the previous line filled.
please show me a way to do that

Comment: Could you provide some additional information (i.e. code example)? Based on the question I'm assuming that you are talking about a `TextBox`. Is that correct? What do you want to achieve? As far as I understand your question `AcceptsReturn=True` would be the correct answer. Why can't you use it?

Answer (score 0):

You must enable wrapping in `TextBox` to make too long text automatically started from the new line

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Comment: @AliFata You may accept the answer if it works for you ;)